# ng-show=false and dynamic link function in directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-show

What happens to an element that it's ng-show value is calculated to be false, but is connected to a directive in which the link function calls something like element.show()? 
Will the element be visible? 
(Same question for ng-if, ng-disable, etc.)

```
<div has-permissions ng-show="someFunctionThatReturnsFalse()"></div>
```

Directive Code:

```
...
link : function(element){
       element.show();
  }
 ...
```

Comment: What happens when you try?

Comment: It all depend on what the function return

Comment: @AlonEitan, the question (and the name of the function) specifies that the return value is `false`

Comment: @NewDev Oh, so in that case they should test and see. Personally I don't understand what good of a practice it would be using a code that has no sense

Comment: The example I gave is a simple one. The function and statements in ng-show or ng-if are dynamic and might be true or false sometimes...